# Make child DIV larger than parent DIV with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make the Child Div of a fix width Parent 100% width, like so:

[image: Child Div 100% width of a fix width Parent]

I am aware that there are multiple questions about this, unfortunately none answer the underlining issue of content not displaying properly underneath the child DIV.

I know that with CSS this is partially achievable:

```
.child-div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.parent-div {
    position: static;
    max-width: 900px;
}
```

I am working within a CMS which means I can't tailor the HTML to open and close the wrapper either which would be the correct solution to this of course. But I know there are people out there that would need to do it this way too for many other reasons.

The other problem is that by using this method, all the content underneath the Child shows up behind the `.child-div`, it doesn't sit underneath. I understand that this because by making it absolute it no longer sits in the flow of the content.

I understand why this wont work, but is there a solution using jQuery or Javascript instead?

http://jsfiddle.net/d4tjkwnc/

Comment: Can you please add your HTML to the question.

Comment: Why blue box is child  ? just move this out

Comment: Try add 'px' `left: 0px;` and define widht/height to test

Comment: fiddle added... @BenjaminPoignant, please read the whole question which explains why this like this

Comment: @BoneStarr I've added a solution that doesn't require Javascript; solves all your issues, have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to solve this problem with just using CSS and without position absolute (if you don't care about [IE8 support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)).

Your CSS should look like this:

```
.child-div {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 100px;
}
.parent-div {
    position: static;
    max-width: 900px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
    .child-div {
        /* 450px is 900px/2 and 50vw is 50% of the viewport */
        margin: 0 calc(450px - 50vw); 
    }
}
```

You basically us the power of negative margins and the `calc()` "function" and since you're not using position absolute, you have all your problems solved.

http://jsfiddle.net/wfverf6d/1/

Comment: In your example this is working but in practice for some reason this makes the div go to the left of the page but not 100% width, its the same width as the parent, 900px.

Comment: What do you mean? It works in the fiddle, do you mean it doesn't work when you are trying to use it? Some other CSS or HTML could be influencing it.

Comment: This does work after a bit of correction from my end... Nice one dude!

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{margin:0 ;padding: 0}
.parent{width:960px; margin:0 auto;height: 750px; border: 1px solid black; }
.child{position: absolute;top:0;width: 100%; margin-top: 100px; border: 1px solid red;height: 100px;background-color: #fff;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Try to avoid using position, unless it is required. I made this mark up based on the wireframe you given.

Comment: And without position, child cant be bigger than a parent element

Comment: yup, made the changes.

Comment: This looks exactly like what he has already and doesn't solve his "other problem"

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  position : absolute;
  top : 0;
  bottom : 0;
  left : 25%;
  right : 25%;
  border : solid 2px black;
  border-radius : 2px;
}

.contained {
  border : solid 2px blue; 
  border-radius : 2px;
  position : fixed; /* here is the trick */
  top : 10%;
  left : 0;
  right : 0;
  height : 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="contained">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Use `position : fixed` to reach your goal. When using `absolute` in a `div` you already used `absolute`, it will only stuck to the corner of the container div. `fixed` works with entire viewport.

Comment: This is not correct, absolute will "stick" to the parent container that has position "relative", moreover position "fixed" will make it "fixed" in place when you scroll

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it :

Assuming this markup :

```
<div class="parent">
    [content before]
    <div class="child"></div>    
    [content after]
</div>
```

Here is the CSS :

```
// for decorative purpose
div{min-height:100px;padding:50px 0;}

.parent {
    width:900px; margin:0 auto; // parent width (in px or %) and centering
    background-color:grey;
}
.child {        
    background-color:blue;
}
@media (min-width: 900px) {
    .child {
        position:relative; left:50%; // centered position
        width:100vw; // set width to 100% of the view port width
        margin-left:-50vw;// margin left of 50% of the viewport width
    }
}
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/whytk3xt/4/

Comment: Your solution doesn't really work for his problem, he has a fixed with parent container.

Comment: You can set the .parent container a fixed width. Works the same.

Comment: My bad you're true ... He should use that media query you made.